# Prove that the set of functions $a_k(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}e^{i2\pi k/L}$ are a orthonormal set of functions for $k \in \mathbb Z$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Consinder the space $C(a,b)$ with dot product: $$<f(x)\lvert
>  g(x)>=\int_a^b dx\space f(x)^*g(x)$$
>
> Prove that the set of functions
>    $$a_k(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}e^{i2\pi k/L}$$ are a orthonormal set of
>    functions for $k \in \mathbb Z$

Do I have to show that $<a_k \lvert a_k>=1$ or do I have to show that $<a_1 \lvert a_2>=0,<a_2 \lvert a_3>=0,...$

If I have to show the first option then: $$<a_k \lvert a_k>=\int_a^bdx \space \frac{1}{\sqrt{L} \sqrt{L}} e^{-i2 \pi k x/L}e^{i2 \pi k x/L}=\frac{b-a}{L}=1 \space \space \text{if L is the distance from $a$ to $b$}$$

The second option seems to give an answer $\not=1$: $$<a_1\lvert a_2>=\int_a^bdx \space \frac{1}{\sqrt{L} \sqrt{L}} e^{-i2 \pi 1 x/L}e^{i2 \pi 2 x/L} \\ =\int_a^bdx \space \frac{1}{L}e^{i2\pi x/L}=\frac{1}{L}((\frac{L}{i2 \pi}  )e^{i2 \pi b /L}-(\frac{L}{i 2 \pi} )e^{i 2 \pi a /L}) \\ \not= 0$$

I am guessing there is a mistake in my calculation but I don't know where. Any ideas?

**Edit:** I now know that I have to show both. However $<a_n \lvert a_m>$ does not give me zero. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you want to prove that they are orthonormal, you need to show that $\langle a_n \vert a_n\rangle = 1$ and $\langle a_n \vert a_m \rangle = 0$ for $n \neq m$; i.e. the functions are of unit length and they are mutually orthogonal..

Comment: @LionelRicci Thanks. So basicalliy I just show that $$\int_a^b dx \space (\frac{1}{L})e^{i 2 \pi n x /L}e^{i 2 \pi m x /L}=0 \space \text{?}$$

I tried to show that above but it's not zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show: $\int_a^b \frac{1}{L} e^{-2 \pi inx/L}e^{2\pi imx/L}dx=0$

\begin{align}
<a_n|a_m> & = \int_a^b \frac{1}{L} e^{-2 \pi inx/L}e^{2\pi imx/L}dx \\
 & = \frac{1}{L} \int_a^b e^{2 \pi i x(m-n)/L} dx\\ 
 & = \frac{1}{L} \frac{L}{2 \pi i(m-n)} \left( e^{2 \pi i (m-n) b/L}-e^{2 \pi i(m-n)a/L}\right) \\
 & = \frac{1}{2 \pi i(m-n)}\left( e^{2 \pi i (m-n)(a+L)/L}-e^{2 \pi i(m-n)a/L}\right) \\ 
 & = \frac{1}{2 \pi i(m-n)}\left( e^{2 \pi i (m-n)a/L}\underbrace{e^{2\pi i(m-n)}}_{=1}-e^{2 \pi i (m-n)a/L}\right)\\
& =\frac{1}{2 \pi i (m-n)}(0)=0 \implies \text{orthogonality}
\end{align}

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you!